# Workflow OR logical condition

Tags: designer-workflow

I am working in SP Designer 2010 and have a workflow where I have to use OR condition. If CurrentItem:BlankCnt equals 0 OR -1 . I have to use this. How to execute this condition. I can only see equals to contains, not equals, less , greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  If CurrentItem:BlankCnt equals 0 OR CurrentItem:BlankCnt equals -1
Ref
[Refer MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c4a461d2-3a63-4104-b9c7-a5ed77c40595/how-to-implement-and-and-or-operators-in-designer-2013-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Comment: That's a better solution. Click just below the IF and insert another IF.

Comment: How would you put OR one after other condition I am unable to get it after adding two conditions.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use two IFs in sequence.

- Create a variable and set it to false (or 0 or whatever)
- Add an IF for the first test, and if true set the variable to true (or 1 ...)
- Add a second IF, and if true set the variable to true (or 1 ...)
- Add a third IF that tests the variable.

ANDs are done with nested IFs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the information presented by the link in Shiradhar's answer ([Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c4a461d2-3a63-4104-b9c7-a5ed77c40595/how-to-implement-and-and-or-operators-in-designer-2013-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)) :

You can add a second condition to an If by right-clicking just below the If, and add selecting "If any value equals any value". This will add a second comparison so that you can do something like this:

[image: Right Click Menu]

Then clicking `and` (`or` in my image) you will be able to toggle between the two options.

Comment: how did he inserted OR and And in the loop? I don't find it in my designer. I am using SP2010 designer. I have added two conditions one under other but it won't give and r OR to me

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SPD 2010, only 2013. I've added an edit to your question clarifying that you are using 2010 to help you receive more relevant answers.

Comment: To insert the OR, click just below the IF.